# Checking screen sizes in javascript

Tags: html, css, web, layout, flexbox

How in javascript can you check the screen sizes (in the if) (I mean the size indicated in the media request) and, depending on this check, draw the page content?

Comment: Can you be more specific with the question? If you want something to appear in specific breakpoint, you can refer to  https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I recommend new users review [ask] for tips on writing questions that best enable the community to provide assistance.  Can you include a [mcve] and a clear description of the desired behavior (including visual aids, if helpful)?  As the post is currently written, it is unclear what you need.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you aren't really interested in the screen size but in the viewport size.

If that is so in Javascript you can sense the innerWidth and innerHeight. These return the dimensions as numbers which represent pixels.

```js
console.log('width = ' + window.innerWidth);
console.log('height = ' + window.innerHeight);
```